# GoogleMap on a webpage

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I use the below code for my webpage, but I want the map show the border as in [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH7oA.png).
How can I figure it out?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var map;
var geocoder;
function InitializeMap() {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.646859, 27.883121);
    var myOptions =
    {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: true
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
}

function FindLocation(whichone) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    InitializeMap();

    var control1 = document.getElementById('<%= DDL_Ilce.ClientID %>');
    var selectedvalue1 = control1.options[control1.selectedIndex].text;
    var control2 = document.getElementById('<%= DDL_Mahalle.ClientID %>');
    var selectedvalue2 = control2.options[control2.selectedIndex].text;
    if (whichone == 1) {
        var address = " Balıkesir" ;
    }
    else
    {
        var address = selectedvalue2 + " Balıkesir" ;
    }
    alert(address);
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address, 'region':'Turkey' }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location

            });
        }
        else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });

}

window.onload = InitializeMap;

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in the Polyline method.  As an example place something like this inside your InitializeMap() function:

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
                                   {lat: 39.646859, lng: 27.883121},
                                   {lat: 40.646859, lng: 28.883121},
                                   {lat: 42.646859, lng: 30.883121},
                                   {lat: 43.646859, lng: 32.883121},
                                   {lat: 39.646859, lng: 27.883121}
                                 ];
      var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                              path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                              geodesic: true,
                              strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                              strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                              strokeWeight: 2
                       });

     flightPath.setMap(map);
```

So that your function looks like this now:

```
function InitializeMap(){
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.646859, 27.883121); 
      var myOptions = { zoom: 8, center: latlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, disableDefaultUI: true }; 
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

      var flightPlanCoordinates = [
                                   {lat: 39.646859, lng: 27.883121},
                                   {lat: 40.646859, lng: 28.883121},
                                   {lat: 42.646859, lng: 30.883121},
                                   {lat: 43.646859, lng: 32.883121},
                                   {lat: 39.646859, lng: 27.883121}
                                 ];
      var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                              path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                              geodesic: true,
                              strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                              strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                              strokeWeight: 2
                       });

     flightPath.setMap(map);
}
```

You can read more about it here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes

Comment: GoogleMap is showing the Polygon automaticly. I want it to show on each address search.

Comment: It is ok but where can i get the new flightPlanCoordinates after users next seach.

Comment: That would really depend on the way your code runs.  I would suggest feeding an object into the initializMap function, that holds all of the coordinates.  Then each time they do a search reload the map with the new coordinates.

Comment: Finally as i understand i have to insert all the border coordinates into the code. There is no way to get them from googlemap. Am i right?

Comment: There may be.  But, how would the map know what coordinates you want the border to be located at, if you do not tell it?

Comment: I think i didn't make myself clear. The borders on the example generated by googlemap [link] (https://www.google.com/maps). But in my code there is no border showing.

Comment: Right.  You would need to pass those in.  Aside from that, I'm not sure of any other way to provide them.

The only other idea I'd have would be to Google around for existing borders.  I'm sure Google has some already created, that you could find.